# How to know user reached last item of RecyclerView with FixedGridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am facing issue with FixedGridLayoutManager, unable to know when the user reached the last item in RecyclerView

Here is my code

```
clubAdapter = new ClubAdapter(CaptainDetails.this, captainList, CaptainDetails.this);

    FixedGridLayoutManager manager = new FixedGridLayoutManager();
    manager.setTotalColumnCount(1);
    rvClub.setLayoutManager(manager);
    rvClub.setAdapter(clubAdapter);
    rvClub.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(CaptainDetails.this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));


    rvClub.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            scrollX += dx;

            headerScroll.scrollTo(scrollX, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }
    });
```

My adapter class:

```
public class ClubAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClubAdapter.ClubViewHolder> implements Filterable {
private static final int TYPE_ROW = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ROW_COLORFUL = 1;

private List<Club> clubList;
private List<Club> filteredClubList;
private Context context;
private Activity activity;

public ClubAdapter(Context context, List<Club> clubList, Activity activity) {
    this.context = context;
    this.clubList = clubList;
    this.filteredClubList = clubList;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        return TYPE_ROW_COLORFUL;
    }

    return TYPE_ROW;
}

@Override
public ClubViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_ROW) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_club, viewGroup, false);
        return new ClubViewHolder(view);
    } else {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_club_colorful,
                viewGroup, false);
        return new ClubViewHolder(view);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ClubViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Club club = filteredClubList.get(position);

    holder.captainNametv.setText(club.captainName);
    holder.captainMobileNumbertv.setText(club.getCaptainMobileNumber());
    holder.ridesCounttv.setText(String.valueOf(club.getRidesCount()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filteredClubList.size();
}

public class ClubViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView captainNametv, captainMobileNumbertv, ridesCounttv;
    ImageView captainProfilePicFlag, captainDLFlag, captainRCFlag, captainActiveFlag;
    LinearLayout captainDetailsMainLL;

    public ClubViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        captainNametv = view.findViewById(R.id.captainNametv);
        captainMobileNumbertv = view.findViewById(R.id.captainMobileNumbertv);
        ridesCounttv = view.findViewById(R.id.ridesCounttv);
        //captainMobileFlag = view.findViewById(R.id.captainMobileFlag);
        captainProfilePicFlag = view.findViewById(R.id.captainProfilePicFlag);
        captainDLFlag = view.findViewById(R.id.captainDLFlag);

        captainRCFlag = view.findViewById(R.id.captainRCFlag);
        captainActiveFlag = view.findViewById(R.id.captainActiveFlag);
        captainDetailsMainLL = view.findViewById(R.id.captainDetailsMainLL);
    }
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                filteredClubList = clubList;
            } else {
                List<Club> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Club club : clubList) {
                    // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                    // here we are looking for name
                    if (club.captainMobileNumber.contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                        filteredList.add(club);
                    }
                }

                filteredClubList = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filteredClubList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            filteredClubList = (ArrayList<Club>) filterResults.values;

            // refresh the list with filtered data
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: I think I have a work around, but first can you tell me how are you using the `FixedGridLayoutManager` class. Are you using some library or directly added the class file to your project?

Comment: Hi @RickSanchez, i was using some library for FixedGridLayoutManager class

Comment: can you point me to the library? Actually there is a change required in `FixedGridLayoutManager` class. If you have the source code and you are compiling the source yourself then may be I can help you.